# Seed Database with Users after adding custom fields MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've added a couple of custom fields to my ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public enum BUserType {IndividualBuyer, IndividualSeller, Broker, Admin};
    public string DisplayName;
    public BUserType UserType;
```

I've updated all the views and controllers and I can create new users through my web app. Great.

However, my database seed function doesn't add the new fields to my users. For example, if I create a new user in my initializer, the new fields aren't filled in.

```
    public class ListingInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {


        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        if (!(context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "arnold@pizzashop.com")))
        {
            var userToInsert = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "arnold@pizzashop.com",  DisplayName = "Arnold Toughguy", UserType = ApplicationUser.BUserType.IndividualSeller };

            userManager.Create(userToInsert, "password1234");

        }
```

So my question is, what could be wrong here? I assume userManager.Create does some fancy reflection-to-linq voodoo to find all the fields to persist. Is this not the case? Do I have to add bindings somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, can you just try once after moving the enum definition outside of your POCO class, though I am not absolutely sure that the same will solve your problem.

You can also refer to this video, which may help you somewhat: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/.